# Connecting to EMQX cloud broker with a node mcu

Tags: mqtt, nodemcu, emqx

I am having trouble connecting to my EMQX broker that is deployed on the cloud. It is a serverless free deployment. I am trying to connect to the broker from my Node MCU. The board connects to the WiFi without an issue and also connects to the publicly available broker i.e.
`broker.emqx.io` But whenever I try to connect to my private broker, the connection fails and I get a return code of either -2 or -4. Why am I getting this problem?

Any sort of help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: You will need to provide significantly more information to enable us to help. I'd suggest confirming that you can connect to your broker with a tool like [MQTTX](https://mqttx.app/), and then edit your question to provide information on that test, along with a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).